# ESXi4 lost the datastore?

Tags: esxi

I have an ESXi 4.1 host with some virtual machine. The host was using an external storage via NFS and local storage with a SATA disk.

I've moved all virtual machines from the NFS datastore to the SATA datastore. Then, i tried to unmount the NFS datastore, but failed with the error that was in use. But, the datasotre was empty.

So, I've used the SSH access to unmount the NFS datastore:

```
~ # esxcfg-nas -l
nfs1 is /vmware from 192.168.2.131 mounted
~ # esxcfg-nas -d nfs1
NAS volume nfs1 deleted.
~ # esxcfg-nas -l
nfs1 is /vmware from 192.168.2.131 unmounted
```

But, now at the vSphere Client, there's a big message showing:

**The VMware ESX Server does not have persistent storage.**

At configuration->Storage, the list is empty, and before remove the NFS datastore, there was the two datastores (NFS and SATA).

But, all seems to be working perfect. All virtual machines continues working.

I tried to Rescan All, with no luck. If I try to add a new storage, the SATA disk appears as available.

What can I do to restore the datastore  ? I'm scared to do anything and lost all my data from the SATA disk.

Any idea ?

Comment: This is not a programming question. It is off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is two very smart people than can downvote my problem without sharing their thoughts.

For all other people with the same problem, I've found the solution. When I try to refresh datastores, although the vSphere Client shows 'Complete', at the file /var/log/messages this is logged:

```
Jun 13 11:32:34 Hostd: [2014-06-13 11:32:34.677 2C3E1B90 error 'FSVolumeProvider' opID=EB3B0782-00001239] RefreshVMFSVolumes: ProcessVmfs threw HostCtlException Error interacting with configuration file /etc/vmware/esx.conf
Jun 13 11:32:34 ker failed : Error interacting with configuration file /etc/vmware/esx.conf: I am being asked to delete a .LOCK file that I'm not sure is mine.  This is a bad thing and I am going to fail.
[...]
Jun 13 11:32:35 ith configuration file /etc/vmware/esx.conf: I am being asked to delete a .LOCK file that I'm not sure is mine.  This is a bad thing and I am going to fail.  Lock should be released by (0)
```

To solve this, just run from the SSH access:

```
# services.sh restart
```

And my SATA datastore appears with no problem.

Hope this helps somebody sometime.